# How to stop button from working until code finishes running?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, button

Using Tkinter and tkmacosx.

I am making a dice roller and when the button is pressed successively multiple times, it would run several times which isn't what I would like the program to do. Here is the code:

```
def rolled_lbl (event):
    global roll_lbl_txt
    sleep(0.2)
    roll_lbl_txt = "You Rolled a" # show at first
    rolling_lbl.place(x=345, y=200)
    for x in range(4): # repeating 4 times as the first time the label stays the same
        rolling_lbl.config(text = (roll_lbl_txt)) # has to be implemented because of the changing variable
        rolling_lbl.update() # update the label on screen
        sleep(0.25) # wait for a better effect
        roll_lbl_txt += "." # adds the dot


# hides previous dice and rolled label
        
def hide_previous(event):
    rolling_lbl.place_forget()  # place.forget is used as i placed the objects in these positions so place.forget removes them
    d1.place_forget() # dice image 1
    d2.place_forget() # dice image 2
    d3.place_forget() # dice image 3
    total.place_forget()  # total value
    window.update() # refreshes window
    sleep(0.2)  # creates better effect so it isnt rushing
    
    



# dice value event
# randomiser uses the number of sides as a maximum value
# this randomised number is then placed into a string text which has the location of the dice images
    
def roll_dice():
    global dice_sides  # to get values from dice sides dropdown
    global dice_value  # to tell the total value codes what the value was
    dice_value = random.randint(1,(dice_sides))
    dice_img= "Resources/Dice_imgs/dice_img_"+str(dice_value) +".png"  #variable with image location must use string as location needs to be in string format
    return dice_img  #returns the location to the image processing function



#event which updates dice images on screen

def update_dice(event):
    global updated_picture 
    global updated_picture_2
    global updated_picture_3
    global value_d1   # for totals function
    global value_d2   # for totals function
    global value_d3   # for totals function
    value_d2 = 0    # must be set to zero otherwise when reducing number of dice, value stays
    value_d3 = 0    # must be set to zero otherwise when reducing number of dice, value stays
    if no_dice == 1:  # if there is only 1 dice running  - from number of dice dropdown
        dice_img = roll_dice()  # gets location from randomiser
        updated_picture = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(dice_img)) # opens location and gets image
        d1.place(x=312 ,y=255)  # puts on screen
        d1.configure(image = updated_picture)  # ensures image is updated picture
        value_d1 = dice_value  # tells total the first dice value - must be done because Dice_value is used for dice 2&3 as well

        
    elif no_dice == 2:  # if there is 2 dice running from number of dice dropdown - reuses same code from above for the first but changes location, new variables for second
        dice_img = roll_dice()  # gets location 
        updated_picture = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(dice_img)) #runs and opens image
        d1.place(x=110 ,y=255)  # places location of image on screen
        d1.configure(image = updated_picture)  # puts image in location
        value_d1 = dice_value  # tells total value of dice one
        dice_img = roll_dice()  # gets location for dice two - dice one has already been inputed so variable can be reused
        updated_picture_2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(dice_img)) # loads image from location
        d2.place(x=525 ,y=255)  # places on righthand side of screen
        d2.configure(image = updated_picture_2) # updates image
        value_d2 = dice_value  # tells total value of dice two
        
        
    elif no_dice == 3: # if there is 2 dice running from number of dice dropdown - reuses same code from above for the first and second but changes location, new variables for third
        dice_img = roll_dice()  # gets location of dice 1
        updated_picture = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(dice_img))  # loads image
        d1.place(x=46 ,y=255)  # puts location on far left of screen
        d1.configure(image = updated_picture)  # updates image to be new loaded one
        value_d1 = dice_value  # tells total the value of dice one
        dice_img = roll_dice()  # gets location of dice 2 
        updated_picture_2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(dice_img))  # loads image
        d2.place(x=321 ,y=255)   # places in middle of screen
        d2.configure(image = updated_picture_2)  # updates image
        value_d2 = dice_value  # tells total the value of dice two
        dice_img = roll_dice()  # gets location of dice 3
        updated_picture_3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(dice_img))  # loads image
        d3.place(x=596 ,y=255)  # places on right of screen
        d3.configure(image = updated_picture_3) # updates image 
        value_d3 = dice_value  # tells total value of dice three




# Event which runs Total at bottom of screen

def total_lbl (event):
    total_txt = "The total is: "  # original text
    dice_total = (value_d1 + value_d2 + value_d3) # add values of dice one two (if available) and 3 (if available)
    total_txt += str(dice_total)  # adds total of dice to original text
    total.config(text=(total_txt))  # updates label to have text
    total.update()
    total.place(x=350, y=535)

roll=Button(window, text="Roll the Dice", background="red", fg="white", activebackground='#00FF00',font=("Calibri",(30)), width =180, height = 55, borderless=1)
roll.place(x=350, y=120)


# when the button is clicked:
# happens in order shown

roll.bind('<Button-1>', hide_previous, add="+")  # commands hide_previous function to hide old objects
roll.bind('<Button-1>', rolled_lbl, add="+")  # commands rolled_lbl to display you rolled a 
roll.bind('<Button-1>', update_dice, add="+")  # commands update_dice to update dice images and display on screen
roll.bind('<Button-1>', total_lbl, add="+")  # commands total value to display on screen
```

Is there a way to stop the button from running the functions whilst it is going? I don't want to use disable, however.

Could I create a variable that will only let the code work once it has begun and leave the button useless until it has finished all of the 4 functions?

Comment: Try importing the time module. and after the button press event do time.sleep(0.1)

Comment: Uh... I do not see how that will work... The button is binded to 4 functions.

Comment: @UrDistraction do you have any experience with `tkinter`? or `time.sleep`? `tkinter` needs to run on the `.mainloop()` to update itself, sleep will not only freeze the update loop but also the whole other script. for OP `.update()` is not really the best aproach and why can't you have one function that calls the four functions? you can still then call them in order, also please provide a [mre] and don't use `sleep`, instead use `.after()`

Comment: @Matiiss Thank you so much for that. Sorry, I am new to this platform and Python in general. I have implemented .after() but what do you mean by .update()

Comment: Why don't you use `command` option to link a callback to the button and called the four functions inside that callback? Then you don't need the binding at all.  Inside the callback, set `command` option to a dummy function before calling the four functions and then restore `command` option after.

Comment: @pesto_23 I mean that you shouldn't use `.update()`, if you have implemented `.after()` then it will update anyways because it will run the code after those ms and return back to updating